# Problem in minimizing expression

Tags: mathematical-optimization, summation

I am trying to implement bootstrapping (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(finance)) of CDS curve. To implement it I am trying to minimize a series of expression. The minimum value of expression will result from certain value of variable. I can easily do it in excel however trying to find a way in mathematica.

I am trying to find value of h1 and h2 in below code using Minimize function to minimize two expression.

```
'Minimize[Sum[50/10000*1/4*1/4*n*97/100*Exp[-h1*1/4*n], {n, 1, 4}] -
Sum[1/2*1/4*n*97/100*(Exp[-h1*1/4*(n - 1)] - Exp[-h1*1/4*n]), {n, 1, 4}]   
&&   
Sum[77/10000*1/4*1/4*n*97/100*Exp[-h1*1/4*n], {n, 1, 4}] + 
Sum[77/10000*1/4*1/4*n*94/100*Exp[-h2*1/4*n], {n, 5, 8}] - 
Sum[1/2*1/4*n*97/100*(Exp[-h1*1/4*(n - 1)] - Exp[-h1*1/4*n]), {n, 1, 4}] + 
Sum[1/2*1/4*n*94/100*(Exp[-h1*1/4*(n - 1)] - Exp[-h2*1/4*n]), {n, 5}] +
Sum[1/2*1/4*n*94/100*(Exp[-h2*1/4*(n - 1)] - Exp[-h2*1/4*n]), {n, 6,8}],   
{h1, h2}, Reals]'
```

I get following output but doesn't give values of h1 and h2 which will minimize the expression. I get h1 = 0.01148 and h2 = 0.01451 when I use goal seek in excel. Can anybody help in trouble shooting the issue in Minimize function

```
Minimize[(97 E^-h1)/80000 + (291 E^(-3 h1/4))/320000 + (97 E^(-h1/2))/
160000 + (97 E^(-h1/4))/320000 - 97/200 (-E^-h1 + E^(-3 h1/4)) - 
291/800 (-E^(-3 h1/4) + E^(-h1/2)) - 97/800 (1 - E^(-h1/4)) - 
97/400 (-E^(-h1/2) + E^(-h1/4)) && (7469 E^-h1)/4000000 + (
22407 E^(-3 h1/4))/16000000 + (7469 E^(-h1/2))/8000000 + (
7469 E^(-h1/4))/16000000 + (3619 E^(-2 h2))/1000000 + (
25333 E^(-7 h2/4))/8000000 + (10857 E^(-3 h2/2))/4000000 + (
3619 E^(-5 h2/4))/1600000 - 97/200 (-E^-h1 + E^(-3 h1/4)) - 
291/800 (-E^(-3 h1/4) + E^(-h1/2)) - 97/800 (1 - E^(-h1/4)) - 
97/400 (-E^(-h1/2) + E^(-h1/4)) + 47/50 (-E^(-2 h2) + E^(-7 h2/4)) + 
329/400 (-E^(-7 h2/4) + E^(-3 h2/2)) + 47/80 (E^-h1 - E^(-5 h2/4)) + 
141/200 (-E^(-3 h2/2) + E^(-5 h2/4)) + 47/100 (E^(-3 h1/4) - E^-h2) +  
141/400 (E^(-h1/2) - E^(-3 h2/4)) + 47/200 (E^(-h1/4) - E^(-h2/2)) +   
47/400 (1 - E^(-h2/4)), {h1, h2}, Reals]
```

Comment: Are you trying to minimize 2 expressions with the `&&` ?

Comment: yes there are two expression. First expression only uses h1 but second expression uses h1 and h2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
expr1 = Sum[50/10000*1/4*1/4*n*97/100*Exp[-h1*1/4*n], {n, 1, 4}] - 
   Sum[1/2*1/4*n*97/100*(Exp[-h1*1/4*(n - 1)] - Exp[-h1*1/4*n]), {n, 1, 4}];

expr2 = Sum[77/10000*1/4*1/4*n*97/100*Exp[-h1*1/4*n], {n, 1, 4}] + 
   Sum[77/10000*1/4*1/4*n*94/100*Exp[-h2*1/4*n], {n, 5, 8}] - 
   Sum[1/2*1/4*n*97/100*(Exp[-h1*1/4*(n - 1)] - Exp[-h1*1/4*n]), {n, 1, 4}] + 
   Sum[1/2*1/4*n*94/100*(Exp[-h1*1/4*(n - 1)] - Exp[-h2*1/4*n]), {n, 5}] + 
   Sum[1/2*1/4*n*94/100*(Exp[-h2*1/4*(n - 1)] - Exp[-h2*1/4*n]), {n, 6, 8}];

Plot3D[{expr1, expr2}, {h1, -5, 5}, {h2, -5, 5}, ClippingStyle -> None, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

You must minimize some function of the two expressions

```
NMinimize[#, {h1, h2}] & /@
 {Abs[expr1*expr2], Abs[expr1 + expr2], 
  expr1^2 + expr2^2}
```

[image]

You may also wish to constrain the region of interest.

```
NMinimize[{expr1^2 + expr2^2, h1 >= 0, h2 >= 0}, {h1, h2}]
```

[image]

EDIT: Your comment below indicates that you desire both expressions to be zero

```
NSolve[{expr1 == 0, expr2 == 0}, {h1, h2}, Reals]
```

> {{h1 -> 0.00998752, h2 -> -0.000767111}}

Comment: thanks. not sure why h2 is so far away from what I get from excel goal seek. I expect h2 to be bigger than h1 in this particular case as second expression starts with 77 but 1st expression starts with 50. h is supposed to fit exponential function p= exp(-h*t), p = 1 when t =0, h is increasing function  but peicewise constant. In this case constant between n = 1 to 4 which is h1. h increased and again constant between n =5 to 8 which is h2. Can you pl suggest how do I modify your code to take into these property of h?

Comment: I need to minimize a system of five equation using h1 to h5. Can I just use the same logic as given in your code and extend it to 5 equation please

Comment: Can you pl explain why you decided to minimize {Abs[expr1*expr2], Abs[expr1 + expr2],   expr1^2 + expr2^2}? What are alternatives available please? Is that something you decide after seeing how the expression behaves after plotting in a graphical format pleas?

Comment: However many expressions you have, you need to define a function of those expressions that you want to minimize. In your Excel solution, what function of the expressions were you minimizing?

Comment: Your second expression goes to minus infinity as h2 approaches minus infinity. Consequently, to get a minimum other than minus infinity the range must be constrained or the function to be minimized must use the `Abs`, square, or similar function of `expr2`.

Comment: In excel I am just minimizing  expr1 to get value as close to zero first to derive value of h1. I use the value of h1 in the expr2 and again try to get value as close to zero for expr2

Comment: ok in that case is it possible to minimize expr1 and expr2 to get value as close to zero?

Comment: See edit above: `NSolve[{expr1 == 0, expr2 == 0}, {h1, h2}, Reals]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24792/discussion-between-kausik-and-bob-hanlon).